# What is sla device in Linux /dev/

Tags: linux

I used "df -h" to check my Linux partition and saw "/dev/sla2,3,4".

What is "sla" device?

Comment: I've heard of `sd`, `sg`, `sr`, but not `sl`.  What does `udevadm info -n sla` have to say?

Comment: Could be related with modems?

Comment: You could ask this question to http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `ls -l /dev/sla2,3,4` and it will display two numbers right after user and group fields. These are the device major and minor numbers (they only exist for device special files). Then, check with http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/devices.txt or another similar list to what device class the major number corresponds. If this list doesn't answer your question, you can check the kernel sources on the web, a complete list of major/minor numbers and their meanings must be in there in one form or another.